# How do I attach event listener to an opened colorbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, colorbox

I am using the jQuery colorbox. I wish to attach an event handler to the close event **after** I opened the colorbox.
How would I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Colorbox has event hooks that you can use. So, you could bind a function to cbox_open event and in that function, bind a function for close event.

```
$(document).bind('cbox_open', function(){
    $(document).bind('cbox_closed', function(){
       alert('x');
    });
});
```

Comment: for this to work I must know in ADVANCE to opening the colorbox what will be the close handler. Problem is it is decided within the colorbox...what button the user will press inside the color box + the result from the server according to this press, (hence I can't attach it to the button)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. @ItayMoav-Malimovka, it can easily be edited to do as you want, write an if() statement on line 2. This should be marked as correct.

Answer (score 2):

set the [`onClosed`](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox#setting-onclosed) callback to a function reference, then change that function after you receive the input from the user.

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdM27/1/)

something like:

```
// initialize your callback function
var closeEvent = function() {
    console.log('not handled');
};

$(".group1").colorbox({
    rel:'group1',
    onComplete: function() {
        // set the callback function after the colorbox has been opened 
        // (can substitute your own custom button event in leiu of this onComplete event)
        closeEvent = function() {
            console.log('handled');
        }
    },
    onClosed: function() { closeEvent() }
});

​
```